# Removing duplicates based on column field and modify it

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates

Lets say we have the following List/IEnumerable

```
Program : CPE, ECE
```

Old list:

```
Name            Assigned_Area    Program
Ivan Matala     Mathematics      CPE
Ivan Matala     Mathematics      ECE
Jeremy Cruz     Science          ECE
Ivan Matala     Science          CPE
NJ Aquino       Engineering      CPE
MJ Catanaoan    Engineering      ECE
```

New list:

```
Name            Assigned_Area    Program
Ivan Matala     Mathematics      All Programs
Jeremy Cruz     Science          ECE
Ivan Matala     Science          CPE
NJ Aquino       Engineering      CPE
MJ Catanaoan    Engineering      ECE
```

Basically, what I want to do is to merge every record whose 'Name' and 'Assigned_Area' field are the same, and if each record has both programs (in our case: 'CPE' and 'ECE'), then it should just collapse into a single row whose Program is now 'All Programs'.

How do we do it using LINQ?

What I've tried so far is the following incomplete code

```
var newlist = oldlist.GroupBy(x => x.Assigned_Area);
```

basically, i was thinking of grouping those records that have the same assigned area, but the code above is incomplete since it only considers a single field (i need to consider 2 fields which are 'Name' and 'Assigned_Area'), and then, ill count if the each grouping has a count of two,, and if it has a count of two, then i shall collapse it into one record and just replace the program with 'All Programs'.

---

Followup question but is related to above..

The above question applies to non anonymous classes. Basically, my real problem is that, I have the following code

```
  public IEnumerable GetOfficialList(int visitID)
        {
            db = new PACUCOADB5Entities();

            var x = (from a in db.Accreditor_Program
                     orderby a.Accreditor.Given_Name, a.Accreditor.Middle_Initial, a.Accreditor.Surname, a.Assigned_Area, a.Program.Requested_Program ascending
                     where a.Program.Visit.VisitID == visitID
                     select new
                     {
                         a.Accreditor.Title,
                         a.Accreditor.Given_Name,
                         a.Accreditor.Middle_Initial,
                         a.Accreditor.Surname,
                         a.Assigned_Area,
                         a.Program.Requested_Program
                     }).ToList();

         return x
     }
```

As you can see, 'x' is my list/IEnumerable and Im trying to apply the same concept to the code I am working into... Basically, I want to do the same, but my  attempt was unsuccessful with the following code

```
var newx = x.GroupBy(xx => new {xx.Title,xx.Given_Name,xx.Middle_Initial,xx.Surname,xx.Assigned_Area})
                .Select(xx => new {xx.Key.Title, xx.Key.Given_Name, xx.Key.Middle_Initial, xx.Key.Surname, xx.Key.Assigned_Area, xx.Count() == 2 ? "All Programs" :x.First(y => y.Title == xx.Key.Title && y.Given_Name == xx.Key.Given_Name && y.Middle_Initial == xx.Key.Middle_Initial && y.Surname == xx.Key.Surname && y.Assigned_Area == xx.Key.Assigned_Area).Requested_Program));
```

but Intellisense through me the error

[image]

How do we fix it? How do we remove duplicates given that code. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
oldList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.AssignedArea })
       .Select(g => g.Count() == 1
           ? new Entity(g.Key.Name, g.Key.AssignedArea, g.Single().Program)
           : new Entity(g.Key.Name, g.Key.AssignedArea, "All programs")
       );
```

Here `Entity` is your class with `Name`, `AssignedArea`, and `Program` fields (there isn't its name in your code). All of this will work with the assumption that the count of programs may be either 1 or 2

Comment: what if the Entity type is not an ordinary class, but an anonymous type

Comment: It's not a problem. Just create anonymous class inside select. F.e. `new { g.Key.Name, g.Key.AssignedArea, g.Count() == 1 ? g.Single() : "All programs" }`.

Comment: can you take a look at this? http://puu.sh/f8yRl/95af8d1c34.png  thanks.. ive tried your code, but intellisense says, http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Al12.png

Comment: Oh, of course. Should be `new { g.Key.Name, g.Key.Assigned_Area, Program = g.Count() == 1 ? g.Single().Program : "All programs" }`. It's necessary to give the name for a field of an anonymous class.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
var result = v.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Assigned_Area})
              .Select(x => new EntityName(x.Key.Name, 
                                          x.Key.Assigned_Area, 
                                          x.Count() == 2 ? "All Programs" :v.First(y => y.Name == x.Key.Name && y.Assigned_Area== x.Key.Assigned_Area).Program) );
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/WYJF34740)

Comment: @Shree, I was using your code for my updated question, the concept is the same but situation is different. What might went wrong? Thanks

Comment: Note that my `Select` actually calls the class constructor, whereas you are again creating an anonymous object. I suspect that's the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a better way but here's my attempt:

```
Person[] r = list.GroupBy(p => new { p.Name, p.AssignedArea })
                 .Select(g => g.ToArray())
                 .Select(g => g.Length > 1
                              UpdateProgram(g.First()) :
                              g.First())
                 .ToArray();

private static Person UpdateProgram(Person p)
{
    p.Program = "All Programs";
    return p;       
}
```

---

But personally I'd go with grouping expression and regular foreach loop:

```
foreach (var g in list.GroupBy(p => new { p.Name, p.AssignedArea }))
{
    var p = g.First();
    if (g.Count() > 1)
    {
        p.Program = "All Programs";
    }
    yield return p;
}
```

Comment: What about the `Name` requirement?

Comment: Would the preference for grouping + foreach loop be due to performance reasons, or readability?

Comment: @shree.pat18: Pure LINQ works well when there are no values assignment. As you can see in other answers it introduces a mess and worsens readability thus maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

I literally took the answer of [Mark Shevchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1051621/mark-shevchenko) and updated considering multiple rows with same Name, AsisgnedArea and Program:

```
list
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Area })
.Select(g =>
    g.Select(x=>x.Programs).Distinct().Count() == 1 ?
    new Data {Name=g.Key.Name, Area=g.Key.Area, Programs=g.First().Programs} :
    new Data {Name=g.Key.Name, Area=g.Key.Area, Programs="All programs"});
```

You can test this with:

```
public struct Data
{
    public string Name;
    public string Area;
    public String Programs;
}

void Main()
{
    var list= new List<Data>()
    { 
        new Data(){ Name="Ivan Matala", Area = "Mathematics", Programs = "CPE" },
        new Data(){ Name="Ivan Matala", Area = "Mathematics", Programs = "ECE" },
        new Data(){ Name="Jeremy Cruz", Area = "Science", Programs = "ECE" },
        new Data(){ Name="Ivan Matala", Area = "Science", Programs = "CPE" },
        new Data(){ Name="NJ Aquino", Area = "Engineering", Programs = "CPE" },
        new Data(){ Name="MJ Catanaoan", Area = "Engineering", Programs = "ECE" },
        new Data(){ Name="MJ Catanaoan", Area = "Science", Programs = "CPE" },
        new Data(){ Name="MJ Catanaoan", Area = "Science", Programs = "CPE" }
    };
}
```